# Не могу разобраться с потоками и контролами

Tags: c#, .net

Не могу разобраться с потоками и контролами формы. Когда создаю отдельный поток, в нём произважу вычисления, а в основом потоке обновляю контролы, то форма зависает, пока не обновиться контрол. Тоже самое, когда обращаюсь из вторичных потоков через делегаты к контролам, форма всёровно зависает. 
Например вот.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Thread t = new Thread(test);
            t.Start();

    }

    private void test()
    {

              this.akk = File.ReadAllLines(this.fileName);

            while(i < this.akk.Length)
            {
                l.Add(this.akk[i]);
                i++;
            }

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< this.l.Count; i++)
            textBox3.AppendText(l[i]);
    }
```

Попробовал через BackgroundWorker, получилось такое

```
      Test t = new Test();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

            textBox1.AppendText(e.UserState.ToString());
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i, t.var = i);

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Completed");
    }

}

public class Test
{
    public int var { get; set; }
}
```

И всёровно форма висит, пока незавершится цикл и не запишет всё в textBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере с BackgroundWorker обновления происходят часто - на каждой итерации цикла. К тому же в обработчике обновления `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` есть код:

```
void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {    
            textBox1.AppendText(e.UserState.ToString());
    }
```

Скорее всего, постоянный вызов AppendText и приводит к подвисанию. По идее, в `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` надо вывести статус в процентах, а результат отобразить только в `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted`

PS Если в `ProgressChanged` всё же надо обращаться к данным, которые обрабатывютя в другом потоке, уточните что это потокобезопасно.

Пример BackgroundWorker в msdn [Пример BackgroundWorker в msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: Всё таки из-за частого вызова. 
Ставлю System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5); и работает, когда убераю задержку, форма висит

Answer (score 2):

Можете попробовать принудительное обновление `UI` через `Application.DoEvents`, однако более хороший способ - использовать для ваших целей [**BackgroundWorker,**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097284/update-ui-from-multiple-worker-threads-net) специально для этого и предназначенный.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего дело в том, что обновления вызываются слишком часто и форма только и делает, что обновляется. Попробуйте сделать две вещи - сделать таймер пореже (500 мс) и ограничить время выполнения `OnTimer` каким-нибудь разумным временем, типа 100-200 мс. В отдельной переменной сохранить точку, с которой продолжать обновление на следующей итерации таймера.
Тогда между таймерами у формы будет время обрабатываться и действия пользователей.

Другой вариант - вставить обновление в обработчик `Application.Idle`, но в этом случае его следует ограничить по времени еще сильнее.

Comment: Попробовал поигрался с интервалом, всёровно висит (